# Is it posible to cache bundles in Webpack dev server?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, build-time

I have a large Vue application that is being bundled with Webpack. The bundle time is around 2 minutes, and I have not found a way to improve it much.

For development purposes, I am using `webpack-dev-middleware` and `webpack-hot-middleware`. I would like to find a way to avoid waiting the whole bundle time every time I start the development server - specially when the code has not changed at all.

Is it possible to cache old builds so that, is nothing has changed, `webpack-dev-middleware` reuses them instead of building the code all over again? Can you think of any other way of improving this situation?

Comment: Simplest solution? Use [vite](https://vitejs.dev/). Works with Vue2 and Vue3.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. It looks good and I will give it a try in the next project I start from scratch. In this case, however, I would love to find a solution within Webpack, because I have quite a complex Webpack configuration and migrating everything to Vite could take a good deal of work.